# whisker size of boxplot matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, boxplot

I was trying to plot a boxplot in matplotlib, then I realized the length of one of the whiskers is not right. I calculated the IRQ, q1 and q3 `(16.0 , 62.0 and 78.0)`. I used this command:

```
plt.boxplot(box_plot_data,showmeans=True)
```

I expected the lower limit of whisker should be `$q1-(1.5*IRQ)$` which is 38 but in the plot is 40.

Thank you in advance.

By the way my data is something like this:

```
value1 = [82,76,24,40,67,69,62,75,78,71,32,98,89,78,67,72,82,87,66,56,52]
```

[image]

Comment: As a float, determines the reach of the whiskers to the beyond the first and third quartiles. In other words, where IQR is the interquartile range (Q3-Q1), the upper whisker will extend to last datum less than Q3 + whis*IQR). **Similarly, the lower whisker will extend to the first datum greater than Q1 - whis*IQR.**, where the default `whis=1.5`.  Which, in this case, is `40`.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney thank you so much, I didn't realize that it just shows the first datum. Thanks again

Comment: I didn't realize it either.